# Open sets in a product of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X_i,d_i), i=1,2,\dots,n$ be metric spaces. Let $X=\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and let $(X,d)$ be the metric space defined in the standard manner. For $i=1,2,\dots,n$, let $O_i$ be an open subset of $X_i$. Prove that the subset $O_1 \times O_2 \times \dots \times O_n$ of $X$ is open and that each open subset of $X$ is a union of sets of this form.

Here the standard manner for converting a product of sets into a metric space is by using the metric, $$d(x,y)= \max\{d_i(x_i,y_i)\}, i=1,\dots ,n$$

$$x,y \in X.$$
I've managed to prove the first part, that is I have shown that the product of open sets is open. I'm stuck on showing that any open subset of $X$ is the union of sets who are themselves products of open sets. I know that open sets are unions of open balls, so if I can show that open balls can be written as products of open sets then I am done. Any hints on how to finish this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show $B(x,\epsilon) = \prod_i B(x_i, \epsilon)$. This follows from the $\max$ metric you have defined. Every open set $U$ can be written as $\cup_{x \in U} B(x,\epsilon_x)$, where $\epsilon_x >0$ for all $x \in U$ (for some particular $\epsilon_x$, of course).

Comment: would defining epsilon as the smallest epsilon of each of the open balls in the product work here? @copper.hat

Comment: I don't understand your question. The above expression shows that the open ball in the product space is the product of open balls. If a set is open, and $x$ is an element of the set, then there is some $\epsilon>0$ (which depends on $x$) such that $B(x,\epsilon)$ is also contained in the set. The expression $B(x,\epsilon) = \prod_i B(x_i, \epsilon)$ is true regardless because you are using the $\max$ metric.

Comment: I just don't see how it follows from the metric. In your first comment you mentioned that I had to show $B(x,\epsilon)=\prod_iB(x_i,\epsilon)$, which is why I thought I had to choose an epsilon for the open ball in the product space. @copper.hat

Comment: Miguel, I added an answer below which hopefully explains what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ is an open set in $X$ then, by definition, for any $x \in U$
there exists some $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_x) \subset U$. Then we have $U = \cup_{x \in U} B(x,\epsilon_x)$. So, if we show that $B(x,\epsilon_x)$ is the product of open sets, we are finished.

I claim that for any $x \in X$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ we have
$B(x,\epsilon_x) = \prod_i B(x_i, \epsilon)$.

This follows from the sequence of equivalences: $y \in B(x,\epsilon_x)$ **iff** $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ **iff**
$\max_i(d_i(x_i,y_i)) < \epsilon$ **iff** $d_i(x_i,y_i) < \epsilon$ for all $i$
**iff** $y_i \in B(x_i,\epsilon)$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show the the projection maps
$$
\pi_i :X=X_1\times\cdots\times X_n\to X_i, \quad\text{with}\quad \pi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_i,
$$
are open, i.e., they take open subsets of $X=X_1\times\cdots\times X_n$ to open subsets of $X_i$.

Assume that $U\subset X$ is open, and $x_i=\pi_i(x)\in \pi_i(U)$, where $x\in U$. Then there exists an open $V$ neighbourhood of $x\in U$, in $U$, i.e., $V\subset U$. Hence, there is an $\varepsilon>0$, such that
$$
B_X(x,\varepsilon)=\prod_{i=1}^nB_{X_i}(x_i,\varepsilon)\subset U,
$$ 
where $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, and thus
$$
B_{X_i}(x_i,\varepsilon)=\pi_i\big(B_X(x,\varepsilon)\big)\subset \pi_i(U).
$$
Therefore $\pi_i$ is indeed an open mapping. Thus if $U_1\times\cdots\times U_n$ is open, so are
$$
U_i=\pi_i(U_1\times\cdots\times U_n).
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having trouble seeing how this answers my  question. I'm not too familiar with projection maps either.@Yiorgos S. Smyrlis

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember 2 things:

1. Opened ball is an opened set. Let's denote it as $B$.
2. $\forall x \in B$ you can find subset $O_1×O_2×⋯×O_n \subset B$ and $x \in O_1×O_2×⋯×O_n$. This fact is pretty obvious for opened balls. Then to get whole opened ball you have to take the union of $O_1×O_2×⋯×O_n$ over all $x$ in $B$.

Then every opened set is a union of opened balls and every one of them is a union of $O_1×O_2×⋯×O_n$.